# Removing a loop to make code run faster (Kotlin) (Big O)

Tags: kotlin, time-complexity, big-o

I'm trying a leetcode challenge and am struggling to pass the challenge due to the speed of my code:

```
class Solution {
    fun longestPalindrome(s: String): String {
        var longestPal = ""
        var substring = ""
        for (i in 0..s.length) {
            for (j in i + 1..s.length) {
                substring = s.substring(i, j)
                if (substring == substring.reversed() && substring.length > longestPal.length) {
                    longestPal = substring
                }
            }
        }
        return longestPal
    }
}
```

I'm a newb and not familiar with Big O notation.
I imagine if I could use just one loop I would be able to speed this code up significantly but am not sure how I would go about this.

Answer (score 1):

(Not saying this is the best approach, but that is a start)

Palindromes can only be found between two same letters. So one idea is to go through the string once, and keep track of letter indexes. When you encounter a letter you already saw before, and the difference in indexes is longer than the current longest palindrome, you check for a palindrome:

```kotlin
fun longestPal(s: String): String {
  val letters = mutableMapOf<Char, MutableList<Int>>()
  var longest = ""
  s.indices.forEach { index ->
    val indicesForCurrentChar = letters[s[index]] ?: mutableListOf()
    for (i in indicesForCurrentChar) {
      if ((index - i) < longest.length) break // (1) won't be the longest anyway
      val sub = s.substring(i, index + 1)
      if (sub == sub.reversed()) longest = sub

    }
    indicesForCurrentChar.add(index)
    letters[s[index]] = indicesForCurrentChar
  }
  return longest
}
```

What is costly here is the palindrome check itself (`sub == sub.reversed`). But the check in (1) should contain it (think of a string which is the repetition of the same letter).

I would be curious to know what other suggest online.

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs in `O(n^3)` time, a loop within a loop within a loop, because that `reversed()` call iterates up to the size of the input string. You can look up [Manacher's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_palindromic_substring) for an explanation of how to do it in linear time (`O(n)`), no nested iteration at all.